# getting the current user entries from elementapi

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, plugin-elementapi

How do I use the elementapi to get the list of entries for the logged in user?

I've tried a couple of options to no avail, like

```
'api/v1/user/<userId:\d+>.json' => function($userId) {

            $author = craft()->users->getUserById($userId);

            return [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => [
                    'section' => 'jobs',
                    'author' => $author
                ],
...
```

as an example of one I thought should have worked but it just returns everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the entries for the *currently logged in user*, having a parameter for `userId` in your endpoint URL doesn't really make sense.

Not tested, but something like this should work:

```
'api/v1/user.json' => function () {

    $author = craft()->userSession->getUser();

    if (!$author) {
        HeaderHelper::setHeader(array('status' => 404));
        craft()->end();
    }

    return [
        'elementType' => ElementType::Entry,
        'criteria' => [
            'section' => 'jobs',
            'authorId' => $author->id,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Notice that the above example endpoint would be available at `http://example.com/api/v1/user.json`, where your example code would create an endpoint with a required `userId` parameter, i.e. `http://example.com/api/v1/user/12345.json`.

Also notice that the currently logged in user is pulled via the [UserSessionService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService) (`craft()->userSession`).

Finally, note that you should use `'authorId' => $author->id` in your criteria – not `'author' => $author`.